# ActionScript How to access child Sprites

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have the following problem. Would appreciate if someone takes the pains to answer it.

Problem Description: I have a top level Sprite "TopLevel",
there is a Sprite under it "allRoutes",
there is child Sprite under it "Routes" and
there is another child under it "Route".

I want to access each level in a loop. I have tried doing it in ActionScript but not with success.

Here is the probable code (it is not compiled successfully):

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class TopLevel extends Sprite {
        public function TopLevel() {
            var allRoutes:Sprite = new Sprite();
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                var routes:Sprite = new Sprite();
                for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    var route:Sprite = new Sprite();
                    route.name = "Route:" + i + ", " j;
                    routes.addChild(route);
                }
                routes.name = "Routes:" + i;
                allRoutes.name = "AllRoutes";
                allRoutes.addChild(routes);
            }
            addChild(allRoutes);

            trace (allRoutes.name);
            for (i = 0; i < allRoutes.numChildren; i++) {
                trace(allRoutes.getChildAt(i).name);
                for (j = 0; j < allRoutes.getChildAt(i).numChildren; j++) {
                    trace(allRoutes.getChildAt(i).getChildAt(j).name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting the following result:

AllRoutes

Routes-1

Route-1, 1

Route-1, 2

Route-1, 3

Route-1, 4

Routes-2

Route-2, 1

Route-2, 2

Route-2, 3

Route-2, 4

so on..

Hope you get the picture. 
Thank you very much in advance.

thanks and regards

rr23850

Comment: Compile error which I am getting is: Second level of getChildAt() is not working. It is treating inner Sprite as DisplayObject. Now all function under DisplayObject are different from Sprite, like it does not have getChildAt or numChildren. What is the way out.

Comment: You say 'under it', that's not the same as 'inside of it', which it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globally your code is fine, except some little things :

- You forgot to declare `i` and `j` variables :

```
var i:int, j:int;
```

- You forgot the concatenation operator before `j` in this line :

```
route.name = "Route:" + i + ", " + j;
```

- If your are compiling with the [strict mode](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/debugging-actionscript-3-0.html#main-pars_heading_6), these instructions will fire errors :

```
allRoutes.getChildAt(i).numChildren
```

and

```
allRoutes.getChildAt(i).getChildAt(j).name
```

which can be in that case :

```
for (j = 0; j < Sprite(allRoutes.getChildAt(i)).numChildren; j++) 
{
    trace(Sprite(allRoutes.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(j).name);
}
```

...

And as your `for` loops are starting by `0`, you will get something like this :

```
AllRoutes
Routes:0
Route:0, 0
Route:0, 1
Route:0, 2
Route:0, 3
Routes:1
Route:1, 0
Route:1, 1
...
```

Hope that can help.